# Adding column filters to Angular collapsible material table

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using angular material table with collapsible feature. I have following code block according to the angular material documentation. But it's not working wit my data source. Does anyone know what's the issue with that?

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>
```

**JS**

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
  this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

data format (console.log(this.dataSource.data))
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need to define custom `filterPredicate` since default implementation will not work as expected in some cases.

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function (data:Element, filter: string){
  // return true if filter string match with the data Element
}
```

Comment: found solution from above tip. Thanks